# Showing that a point is in the image

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function.  Let $X$ be a connected set.  Let $x_1, x_2 \in X$ and $y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_1)<y<f(x_2).$  Show that $y \in f(X)$.

Would this follow from the Intermediate Value Theorem?

By the IVY, we know that there exists a $c \in X$ such that $f(c)=y.$  Hence $y \in f(X)$.

I'm not so confident in this argument since its so short.

Comment: you have to use connectivity of $X$ and continuity of $f$ to complete the argument. This is not necessarily true if $X$ is not connected or if $f$ is not continuous

Comment: @JohnMartin: note that the connectivity of $X$ is part of the hypothesis in this case

Comment: @MPW I see that, but the OP has to use that the image of a connected set under a continuous function is connected in order to apply the theorem...

Answer (score 2):

The continuous image of a connected space is connected, and the only connected spaces in $\;\Bbb R\;$ are intervals, so since $\;f(X)\subset\Bbb R\;$ is connected it is an interval.

Try now to take it from here.

Comment: So at this point I could invoke the Intermediate Value Theorem?

Comment: @SamSam Not quite as your function is a real valued non-real one, but you can use the following simple (trivial, according to some definition) property of real intervals: if $\;I\subset\Bbb R\;$ is an interval and $\;x,y\in I\;,\;\;x<y\;$ then for all $\;x<c<y\;$ also $\;c\in I\;$ .

Answer (score 0):

If not, then you immediately have a disconnection of $X$ as 
$$f^{-1}((-\infty,y))\cup f^{-1}((y,\infty))$$

(can you see why these two sets are disjoint, nonempty, open,  and exhaust $X$?).